# How to bring up WordPress post/blog thumbnails on facebook?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, thumbnails

I'm using the automator uncanny plugin and the "recipe" status is working just so I have a little problem about my post/blog thumbnail not showing up.

how to overcome it? should I add the og:image meta tag? if so, what part should I put it in?

[image: 1]

Facebook from wordpress using the automator plugin, only thumbnails of the automatic results do not show on my facebook

Answer (score 0):

1. Use SEO plugin(All in One SEO for WordPress or Yoast…etc / Rank Math is good nowaday)
2. Resize thumbnail image(630*1200..etc)
3. And use facebook debugger site for cleaning facebook cache

Comment: I have also used the Yoast SEO plugin with the premium bundle, and have enabled the social sharing feature for facebook.

thumbnail resizing done in posts or from plugins? and I've tried facebook debuger and the result is no difference (in the condition of clearing the browser cache and restarting the device is complete), as well as clearing the cache of the Litespeed cache.

oh yes my wordpress uses the Cloudflare CDN and for images uses the Quic CDN.cloud from Litespeed plugin

Comment: additionally, cdn quic.cloud is not active but only for image optimization.

Comment: @Hikikomari In my experience, image size specifications matter is important. Because if the size doesn't fit, Facebook will replace it with another random photo or insert a blank image of your own within the post. And I think if setting the image to a different domain from the post is not good way…

Comment: _"and I've tried facebook debuger and the result is no difference"_ - and what does it actually say? Can you give us an example URL?